# Flutter column layout with center widget with inner shadow

Tags: flutter, shadow

I'm trying to achieve the following layout:

safe area, containing a column - in which the center widget (a scrollable list) has an inner-shadow effect

Also, I want to use a **tiled image as a background** for the unsafe-area + the top and bottom widgets in the column (as seen in the attached image).

I don't want to use a **box-shadow** for the center widget.

Is there an easy way to achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `Stack` in this case. you can use nexted `Stack` for `SafeArea`

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => Stack(
        children: [
          Container(   ///background image
            color: Colors.pink,
          ),
       
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              height: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.green, boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  offset: Offset(0, 10),
                  blurRadius: 10,
                )
              ]),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Container(
              height: constraints.maxHeight * .1,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red, boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.black87,
                  offset: Offset(0, -10),
                  blurRadius: 10,
                )
              ]),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: constraints.maxHeight * .8 - 20, //remove shadow area
              child: ListView(
                children: List.generate(
                    44,
                    (index) => Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                          height: 70,
                          color: index.isEven
                              ? Colors.deepPurple
                              : Colors.cyanAccent,
                        )),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```